# Get HTML form element when respective form value is null.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Have a form, need to validate it.

Have used `serializearray` to get all the form elements on clicking submit button.

Parsing trough each value, if value is null need to add a class to respective HTML element.

Code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sumbit_button").click(function(){
        var formElements = $("#ImageSliderForm").serializeArray();
        $(formElements).each(function(x){
            if(formElements[x]["value"] == ""){
                //get the respective html element and add a class
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Need a way to find the respective HTML element.

Output of **console.log($("#ImageSliderForm").serializeArray());**

```
[Object { name="ImageSliderImageURL",  value=""}, Object { name="ImageHeader",  value=""}, Object { name="ImageHeaderSubText",  value=""}, Object { name="ImageSliderSubTextURL",  value=""}]
```

Comment: isn't `formElements[x]`  the respective element ?

Comment: formElements[x] is a object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var formElements = $("#ImageSliderForm").serializeArray();

$(formElements).each(function (x, element) {
    if (element.value == "" || element.value == null) {

        //get the respective html element and add a class
        $("[name='" + element.name + "']").addClass('someclass');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Palash for taking time on this. But formElements[x] is a object. it does not add class to the element.

Comment: Thanks Palash... Method worked... better way to do it.. instead of bringing in another parameter `element`...

$(formElements).each(function (x) { 
if (formElements[x].value == "" || formElements[x].value == null) { 

//get the respective html element and add a class 

$("[name='" + formElements[x]["name"] + "']").addClass('someclass'); 
} 
});

Answer (score 1):

If condition is wrong Try this

```
if(formElements[x]["value"] == "" || formElements[x]["value"] == null){
```

Comment: Mark Tick and close if answer was helpful. So that user can refer it further.

Comment: Your Answer helped me to correct the if condition but my question was to add a class to respective HTML element which has value as null

Comment: You can $(elementname).attr("class", "classname")